# Sinatra Partial with data?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am making a super small Sinatra blog application, how could I take entries from a database, format them, and insert them into my layout?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
class Blog < Sinatra::Base
  helpers do
    def partial (template, locals = {})
      erb(template, :layout => false, :locals => locals)
    end
  end

  get "/list" do
    @posts = Post.all
    erb :list
  end
end
```

**list.erb:**

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<%= partial(:post, :post => post) %>
<% end %>
```

**post.erb:**

```
<h1><%= post.title %></h1>
<p><%= post.body %></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<%= erb :"_partial_name", :locals => {} %>
<% end %>
```

the partial template need start with _